# Submit both image and text along with progress bar through form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I have a form that includes both the images and text and all these data needs to be inserted in database.

```
<form action="processupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="UploadForm">
    <input name="name" type="text" />
    <input name="age" type="text" />

    <input name="fileToUpload" type="file" />
    <input type="submit"  id="SubmitButton" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

However i have a particular requirement, i want that user may fill all the the details but when he comes to the upload part, I want a view like this

[image]

where

> - the user fills the text fields
> - selects an image through upload button
> - gets a preview of uploaded image (as shown in the figure)
> - clicks on start button, the progress bar will start till the time image gets uploaded
> - after the above step gets completed, user will click on main submit button and then the entire data should go to the backend

Code for **processupload.php**

```
if (count ($_POST) > 1)
    {
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        $target_dir = "uploads/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $new_filename = $target_dir . uniqid() . '.' . $imageFileType;
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $new_filename))
            {   
                // do something  
            }
     }
```

Script used for the loader is here [@fidlde](http://jsfiddle.net/learner001/Lty0pbmj/). can anyone please tell how i can achieve this functionality

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var progressbox     = $('#progressbox');
    var progressbar     = $('#progressbar');
    var statustxt       = $('#statustxt');
    var submitbutton    = $("#SubmitButton");
    var myform          = $("#UploadForm");
    var output          = $("#output");
    var completed       = '0%';
  $(myform).ajaxForm({
      beforeSend: function() { //brfore sending form
          submitbutton.attr('disabled', ''); // disable upload button
          statustxt.empty();
          progressbox.slideDown(); //show progressbar
          progressbar.width(completed); //initial value 0% of progressbar
          statustxt.html(completed); //set status text
          statustxt.css('color','#000'); //initial color of status text
      },
      uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) { //on progress
          progressbar.width(percentComplete + '%') //update progressbar percent complete
          statustxt.html(percentComplete + '%'); //update status text
          if(percentComplete>50)
              {
                  statustxt.css('color','#fff'); //change status text to white after 50%
              }
          },
      complete: function(response) { // on complete
          output.html(response.responseText); //update element with received data
          myform.resetForm();  // reset form
          submitbutton.removeAttr('disabled'); //enable submit button
          progressbox.slideUp(); // hide progressbar
      }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you understand that `isset($_POST)` always returns true, because it is a super-global and your are not supposed to check this way. It would be wiser to check this instead:

```
if (count ($_POST) > 1)
```

As you have two `<inputs />`, this would be a better choice to check if the input has been entered. Clicking on cancel, will **not** stop the upload process, as it is a single request sent, AFAIK.

Comment: its just a sample code not the final code, however i have made the change in the question, at present my concern is the functionality

Comment: @lyra Are you concerned about cancelling the upload part?

Comment: through the given code i am able to upload the img and text in one go, but i want that first a preview should appear as shown in the image and then on clicking the start upload should begin, cancel should also be an available option.. and then the submission of entire form should be there

Comment: i am submitting the image through <form> and then while submitting the entire form along with img and text i need a <form> again.. but using a nested form is not an option.. so really feeling clueless about how to do it

Comment: You cannot nest a form.

Comment: yes exactly.. and i am not able to understand how to club these 2 parts.. first uploading the image and then the entire form

Comment: @lyra Why do you wanna use two different forms for that in the first place.

Comment: i don't want, its just an idea about submitting image in one form and text in another form and now i wish to create one form where i get functionality of both the form

Comment: Ha ha... I am confused now.

Comment: have a look at the image thru it u will get a better visual about what i am trying to say. i have 2 text and one image upload.. normal flow is that i submit the form and till the time it gets submitted the progressbar is displayed, now want i want is user fills 2 text, uploads the image gets a preview of the uploaded image(as shown in question) clicks on start button, progress bar will start and then when its completed user clicks on main submit button and form gets submitted to backend